# How to make ansi-term wrap lines instead of adding newline so it can fit the window?

Tags: ansi-term, term

[image]

See the screenshot. I typed one long line in the buffer, didn't hit enter but cursor is already on line 3.

This causes multiple problems, eg. when I copy the output of a command from ansi-term to another buffer then it's copied with these additional newlines.

My expectation is that cursor in the above example would still stay at line 1. How can I make ansi-term work like that?

Comment: You want to set the `term-width` variable. Usually you'd do this in a hook, but it doesn't work for `term-mode` -- it mus be setting the variable after the hook. I tried using `advice` as some other answers on this forum recommend, but that didn't work either.